# Change Error Message to An Instruction for Users

Tags: r

When I run this `R` code I get `Error in order(res2$seed): argument 1 is not a vector` as an error message in the `function call at first instance` but when I change the range of `i` to be something different like in `function call at second instance`, I get the expected data frame format that I want.

**The Function**

```
  abc <- function(a, z, n, ar11, p, d, q, sd = sd, j1, arr1, n_cores){
  future::plan(future::multisession)
  n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
  doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)

  message('processing...')
  `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
  i <- a:z
  res <- foreach::foreach(i = a:z, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
    set.seed(i)
    mod <- stats::arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = c(ar11), order = c(p, d, q)), sd = sd)
    best.mod <- forecast::auto.arima(mod, ic = "aicc")
    (cf <- best.mod$coef)
    if (length(cf) == 0) {
      rep(NA, 2)
    } else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
               substr(cf["ar1"], 1, j1) %in% arr1) {
      c(cf, seed = i)
    } else {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
  }
  message(' done!\n')

  res1 = res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]

  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)

  res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))

  res2[order(res2$seed), ]

  res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
  res2[order(res2$seed), ]
}
```

**Call Function at First Instance**

```
abc(a = 280000,  z = 281000, n = 10, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 4, arr1 = "0.80")

#Error in order(res2$seed) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

**Call Function at Second Instance**

```
abc(a = 289800,  z = 289989, n = 10, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 4, arr1 = "0.80")

#ar1   seed
#1 0.8000000 289805
#2 0.8000368 289989
```

I want to change `Error in order(res2$seed): argument 1 is not a vector` when need be to instruction for this `R` function useers to `Try another range of seeds`

Comment: Do you still want it throw an error, just with a different message? Or if you just want a warning, what should the function return? `NULL`?

Comment: I want the function to return `NULL, Try another range of seeds` instead of the error message.

Comment: Why does `res2[order(res2$seed), ]` appear twice, at both the third-to-last and last line?

Comment: It looks like the last two lines are repeated, just with `tibble::tibble()` included in one case. Is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either look before you leap by testing if the `seed` column exists:

```
abc <- function(a, z, n, ar11, p, d, q, sd = sd, j1, arr1, n_cores){

  # ...code as in OP...

  res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))

  if (!("seed" %in% colnames(res2))) {
    warning("Try another range of seeds", call. = FALSE)
  } else {
    res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  }
}

abc(a = 280000,  z = 281000, n = 10, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 4, arr1 = "0.80") 

# processing...
# done!
# 
# Warning message:
# Try another range of seeds
```

Or ask for forgiveness instead of permission using `tryCatch()` and `suppressWarnings()` for a slightly more generic approach:

```
abc <- function(a, z, n, ar11, p, d, q, sd = sd, j1, arr1, n_cores){

  # ...code as in OP...

  res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))

  tryCatch(
    suppressWarnings(res2[order(res2$seed), ]),
    error = \(err) {
      if (grepl("argument 1 is not a vector", err$message)) {
        warning("Try another range of seeds", call. = FALSE)
      } else { 
        stop(err)
      }
    }
  )
}

abc(a = 280000,  z = 281000, n = 10, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 4, arr1 = "0.80")
# processing...
# done!
# 
# Warning message:
# Try another range of seeds
```

That said, it’s better in my opinion to throw an error than a warning when a function doesn’t return the expected output. Especially if other code will depend on the result of this function. You can throw an error with your desired message by replacing `warning()` with `stop()`.